# No mapping found for GET /api/keyservice/key

Tags: spring, rest, spring-rest, eclipse-jee

I'm creating a spring-rest-app.

This is my dispatcher config (I also have a root config that has DataSource bean)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"config", "cache", "dao", "entity", "exception", "rest", "service"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class DispatcherConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public KeyCache keyCache() {
        return new KeyCacheImpl();
    }
}
```

This is my webapp initializer

```
public class TinyURLKeyServiceInitializor implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appcontext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appcontext.register(ConfigurationClass.class);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appcontext));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatchercontext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatchercontext.register(DispatcherConfiguration.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatchercontext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

This is the controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/keyservice")
public class KeyServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private KeyService keyService;

    @GetMapping(value="/key", produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getKey() {
        return keyService.getKey();
    }
}
```

When I startup the Web app and Send - GET http://localhost:7080/api/keyservice/key
I get the following in DEBUG LOG

```
[INFO] Completed initialization in 1006 ms
May 17, 2020 11:56:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-7080"]
[DEBUG] GET "/api/keyservice/key", parameters={}
[WARNING] No mapping for GET /api/keyservice/key
[DEBUG] Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

I've put @EnableMvc for registring MappingHandlers. But still they are not able to detect the mapping between endpoint and controller method.

**I put a debug point in DispatcherServlet.getHandler and it returns null everytime. Has anyone ever faced similar problem?**

Comment: What is the full package name of your controller?

Comment: It's 'rest'. I can see keyServiceController bean created by spring in debug log. So I didn't think that was the peoblem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason I was hitting -

http://localhost:7080/api/keyservice/key

My pom.xml had -

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>7080</port>
                <path>/api/keyservice</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

My Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/keyservice")
public class KeyServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private KeyService keyService;

    @GetMapping(value="/key", produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getKey() {
```

Since context path = /api/keyservice (due to setting in pom.xml), spring was trying to find a mapping for /key. Cleary there is no mapping for /key in my controller.

Removed the controller RequestMapping. And it worked.